# Very Slow simple MySql query with index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

i have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE `messenger_contacts` (
  `number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `has_telegram` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_state` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_city` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_postal` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `operator` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `messenger_contacts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`number`),
  ADD KEY `geo_city` (`geo_city`),
  ADD KEY `geo_postal` (`geo_postal`),
  ADD KEY `type` (`type`),
  ADD KEY `type1` (`operator`),
  ADD KEY `has_telegram` (`has_telegram`),
  ADD KEY `geo_state` (`geo_state`);
```

with about 11 million records.

A simple count select on this table takes about 30 to 60 seconds to complete witch seems very high.

```
select count(number) from messenger_contacts where geo_state=1
```

I am not a Database pro so beside setting indexes i don't know what else i can do to make the query faster?

UPDATE:

OK , i made some changes to column type and size:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messenger_contacts` (
  `number` bigint(13) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `has_telegram` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `geo_state` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_city` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geo_postal` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `operator` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`),
  KEY `has_telegram` (`has_telegram`,`geo_state`),
  KEY `geo_city` (`geo_city`),
  KEY `geo_postal` (`geo_postal`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `type1` (`operator`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now the query only takes 4 to 5 seconds with `*` and `number`

Tanks every one for your help, even the guy that gave me `-1`. this would be good enough for now considering that my server is a low end hardware and i will be caching the `select count` results.

Comment: how many kind of state does geo_state have? and what percentage of state =1 in all kind of state?

Comment: What's the output of `explain extended select count(number) from messenger_contacts where geo_state=1` ? I'd add that to the bottom of your question as that's one useful thing to help debug.

Comment: Error in your mysql: `\`type\` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0''`. There are double single quotes at the of the line.

Comment: @maxhb typo error, fixed

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke there is 33 states in total and state=1 is about 11%(1.1 million) of the table's data

Comment: Your index `geo_state` has only size 4 but the column `geo_state` is int(11).

Comment: Does `COUNT(*)` instead make any difference?

Comment: this might also need an approach from the sysops side of things. What machine are you running this database on (ie. specs)?

Have you done any tuning to the database? What is the database size (in MB/GB)? What is the size of the InnoDB buffer pool?

Comment: @RichBradshaw updated the question

Comment: @jarlh Yes it dose , updated the question

Comment: @Exlord, but you removed the WHERE clause... (Since number column is not not null all rows will be counted. That's why I suggested trying count(*) instead of count(number) - but keeping the WHERE clause.)

Comment: @jarlh it's weird that his explain plan gives the plan that use only the geo_state index and ingore the pk 'number', y would that happen? if we change to select count(*) would it change the index choice? or should make a index like (number,geo_state)?

Comment: using PK as the index to search would be much faster, if you check the explain plan you updated "select count(*)" that only cost 12 sec it should use that index, but the query you asked is using geo_state index,that's y it takes so much time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
select count(geo_state) from messenger_contacts where geo_state=1
```

as it will give the same result but will not use number column from the clustered index?

If this does not help, I would try to change number column into INT type, which should reduce the index size, or try to increase amount of memory MySQL could use for caching indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You did not change the datatypes.  `INT(11)` == `INT(2)` == `INT(100)` -- each is a 4-byte signed integer.  You probably want 1-byte unsigned `TINYINT UNSIGNED` or 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.

It is a waste to index "flags", which I assume `type` and `has_telegram` are.  The optimizer will never use them because it will less efficient than simply doing a table scan.

The standard coding pattern is:

```
select count(*)
    from messenger_contacts
    where geo_state=1
```

unless you need to not count `NULLs`, which is what `COUNT(geo_state)` implies.

Once you have the index on `geo_state` (or an index *starting* with `geo_state`), the query will scan the index (which is a separate BTree structure) starting with the first occurrence of `geo_state=1` until the last, counting as it goes.  That is, it will touch 1.1 millions index entries.  So, a few seconds is to be expected.  Counting a 'rare' `geo_state` will run much faster.

The reason for 30-60 seconds versus 4-5 seconds is very likely to be caching.  The former had to read stuff from disk; the latter did not.  Run the query twice.

Using the `geo_state` index will be faster for *that* query than using the `PRIMARY KEY` *unless* there are caching differences.

`INDEX(number,geo_state)` is virtually useless for any of the `SELECTs` mentioned -- `geo_state` should be first.  This is an example of a "covering" index for the `select count(number)...` case.

[More on building indexes.](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)